# Remove exclusion of resources folder from eclipse build?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, build

I imported my existing maven projects under eclipse.Once imported i found under Java Build Path > Source  resource foulder is
excluded(i can see `Excluded:**`) from build and does not get copied under target > classes directory.

I can remove exclusion manually by selecting `Excluded:**` and then click Remove, But there are large numbers of projects. Is there
a setting in eclipse where i can do it one go ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's part of what Maven does when you let it generate your Eclipse project settings (via the `eclipse:eclipse` plugin/goal). It's quite misleading. However, if you have the `m2e` plugins installed into Eclipse it coordinates things correctly.

What's going on, as best as I can figure: Eclipse's built-in Java builder automatically copies non-Java files found on the build path to the output location (unless they're excluded as you see in your **Build Path**). Problem is, when Maven comes in the picture it, too, wants to copy resources during a build. So to keep the two builders from competing/interfering with each other, Maven instructs Eclipse to ignore resources so it (Maven) can manage copying them during a build.

`m2e` integrates into the Eclipse build process to do the Maven copying of those files, so if you configure the project as an `m2e` project things will "just work," both in Eclipse and if you build from a command line.

I don't know of a way to tell Maven to *not* configure the project this way. To be honest, that's just one of the reasons I prefer to *not* let Maven generate my Eclipse project files; I do a much better job of it and I totally control the specifics rather than relying on whatever the Maven eclipse developers think is best.

Comment: i am using Sonarqube m2e plugin and imported the existing maven projects in to eclipse. So i believe eclipse:eclipse plugin/goal should not
come into picture.

Comment: You also said "Problem is, when Maven comes in the picture it, too, wants to copy resources during a build".But i found resources under
src/main/resources are never copied to target/classes . So i think neither eclipse and nor maven playing its part here.

Comment: Did you import the projects *as Maven projects*? When you right-click on one of these projects do you have a menu option **Maven >** with sub-menu items like **Update Project...*?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I've been looking for the answer and I finally dug it up myself. According to the [M2Eclipse FAQ](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-faq.html) the import intentionally excludes resources. This is because Maven performs special resource handling that includes filtering.

Let Maven do the building for you. Disable automatic building in Eclipse and never build your projects in Eclipse.